# Tokens in fields label of a view

Tags: views, tokens

I have a view where I show the content of fields.
I check "Create a label" for a field. The label shall be filled dynamically based on the content of another field. Is there a way to use tokens? Or is there another way of achieving this?
Thanks

Comment: Look for tutorials on the internet. For example https://www.webwash.net/customize-view-fields-using-twig-in-drupal/

Comment: it is possible to use tokens, but we need more context.
what kind of view it is? nodes? what are the other fields? also nodes? same node type?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The view shows fields of one node type. All other fields are coming from this node type. Actually these nodes are generated by a feed. I can tamper the contents of the fields during import. So the idea is: Tamper field 2 based on the content of field 1. In the view I like to label field 1 using the content of field 2.

Comment: I looked for tutorials since 3 days. I found a lot how to rewrite the output of a field. But not how to rewrite the label.

Comment: Uncheck "Create a label" and rewrite the entire field using Twig.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Maybe I should have mentioned that the contents are numerical and that I need the lable as header in a table and the also to label a view mode created by the chart module. So rewriting the entire field didn't lead to the desired result. Or did I miss something?

Comment: You didn't mention table header, the Views default style displays the label in front of each field.

Comment: Yes, I know. Sorry. Next question will be more precise.